# Error 424 from Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I'm experitmenting with the Twitter API (OAuth). I have a test bed that can tweet from my dev box, but fails in production. I get a status code of 424 returned when trying to tweet.

I can't spot the difference between my live environment and my dev environment so really need to understand what a '424' is, but can find no documentation relating to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a quirk of classic ASP.

FAILS: `Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`

WORKS: `Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")`

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia describes HTTP Response Code 424 as being a Failed Dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_424#4xx_Client_Error). It's introduced by the WebDAV extensions to HTTP (see [the WebDAV RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918)).  It means that the request you made failed as a result of a previous request failing.

As a high level example (although the actual response codes might be different), you might issue a request to get an OAuth ticket or token for your identity.  If this fails and you then make a request using that token, then a 424 might be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't understand though.

I'm using a single user, hard coded consumer key and secret and it works from my dev box but fails in production.

Comment: Nope, I'm doing it all right, but in the production environment all calls to Twitter give a 424. Looks like it might be a proxy issue..?